# How to know about the progress of uiprogressview?

Tags: iphone

I am making an application in which i have put  a progress bar .

I just need to know about the progress of the bar...

How will i come to know about the progress..

Even i want the print the progress bar in a label time to time..

Here, is my code

> ```
> [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
> ```

```
-(void) onTimer {

    [progressView setProgress:5 animated:YES];


    sliderLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f",progressView.progress *100];

}
```

Here ,i have set a timer in viewdidLoad and as and when the progress is raised ,the label

should get updated .

Kindly help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you are doing wrong. Every time your timer invoke you are setting your progressView's progress to 5. So it won't actually progress.

Now for getting your progressView's actual progress you can use `progress` property of UIProgressView.

[The current progress is represented by a floating-point value between 0.0 and 1.0, inclusive, where 1.0 indicates the completion of the task. The default value is 0.0. Values less than 0.0 and greater than 1.0 are pinned to those limits.]

see [UIProgressView](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

UIProgressView have progress between 0.0 to 1.0. 1.0 represent 100% so if you want to set progress somewhere set it between 0.0-1.0.

**Edit:**

Do one thing you know about timer. Create two timer one for setting progressView's progress. don't make it fix. Take a global float value first time 0.0. Every time your timer invoke add some thing in that value let say you are adding 0.1 every time. So when your timere invoke 10th time your value will be 1.0. and your progressView will have progress increasing.

```
- (void)onTimer {
    myValue += 0.1;
    [progressView setProgress:myValue];
}
```

myValue will be a float declared in .h file.

In your second timer you can print the progress of your progressview as you are doing right now. but don't set progress again in second view.

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry kapil...But  even i have set 5,it is progressing but the label is not getting updated..Now i have set it to 1.0 and now it is just speeding up the progress and the label is not getting changed .it shows 100.00 as the text value because i have written  setprogress:1.0.. kindly help

Comment: I updated answer. I think you are creating a sample app right??

Comment: What happening with your implementation is you are first setting progress in the method and than trying to print that. This won't work. Same way you are setting progress to 1.0 that's why your progressview is speeding and getting a total blue progress. its not being incremented. If I understood right you are creating a sample so use as per my updated ans.

Comment: yes,sir but i am not able to do,Please help.. Here is my code..........Ist Timer  ---(void) onTimer {
  [progressView setProgress:0.5 animated:YES]; }    2nd timer    ---
-(void)onTimerLabel {
    
    sliderLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f",progressView.progress *100];

}....but my label text is shown as 50 from starting even and doesnot change and even the progress bar goes upto 50%..please provide some direction

Comment: that is because as I mentioned use dynamic value you are not doing that. you are setting your progressview's progress to 0.5 every time. tht represent 50% progress. Now you are setting fix value than result will be fix.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11291/discussion-between-vishal-dharmawat-and-kapil-choubisa)